# Javascript, trying to condense timing functions

Tags: javascript

So I have a timer function that checks for an item (if it's not found for an extra 5 seconds once every 200ms for 5000 ms) and I am looking to try and condense this function. It gets the job done currently, it just seems like I'm using an excess of code to do it. Here's what I've got:

```
var timeToCheck = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        timeToCheck = false;
    }, 5000);

    var check = {
        init: function() {
            check.checkAgain();
        },
        checkAgain: function() {
            if (timeToCheck) {
                if (currentModules[name]) {
                    //by some act of god, this module exists now
                } else {
                    //still doesn't exists
                    setTimeout(check.checkAgain, 200);
                }
             } else {
                  //doesn't exist after 5 seconds
                  $log.error("Requested module (" + name + ") could not be found at this time.");
             }
          }
      };
      check.init();
```

I'm wondering if I could get any pointers (or help) in making this a little more elegant and less code if possible.

Comment: That would be cleaner with `setInterval` instead of recursive `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be cleaner to call `check` recursively. You should avoid having two separate `setTimeouts` (it could end up netting you unexpected results, especially in a scenario where the `timeouts` are interdependent) - read up on the event loop if you are not familiar with how it works.

```
var TIMEOUT_DUR = 200;
var MAX         = 5000;
var accum       = 0;

function check () {
    if ( accum >= MAX ) {
        $log.error( '...' );
        return;
    }

    setTimeout( function () {
        if ( currentModules[ name ] ) {
            // do things
            return;
        }
        accum += TIMEOUT_DUR;
        check();
    }, TIMEOUT_DUR );
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  You could also get remove the variable `MAX`.  Set `accum` to 5000, subtract `TIMEOUT_DUR` each time, and replace `if(accum>=MAX)` with `if(!accum)`.

Comment: That works in this specific scenario (since 5000 is evenly divisible by 200). Someone trying to adapt this answer might get confused if they tried to implement your decrement solution with a `TIMEOUT_DUR` of 300 (that would result in infinite recursion since `accum === 0` is the only way that the function will return).